# Sympy Cannot create mpf

Tags: python, sympy, nonlinear-optimization

So, I'm trying to solve this nonlinear system of equations and I am getting the error "cannot create mpf". Here's the sympy [link](https://live.sympy.org/?evaluate=k%2Cl%2Cp%2Cq%20%3D%20symbols(%22k%20l%20p%20q%22)%0A%23--%0Afrom%20sympy.solvers.solveset%20import%20nonlinsolve%0A%23--%0Anonlinsolve(%5B1%2Bk*exp(1.401*l)-p%2C%201%2B%20k%2B%20(tanh(l*1.401))**6-q%5D%2C%5Bk%2Cl%5D)%0A%23--%0Afrom%20mpmath%20import%20tanh%0A%23--%0Anonlinsolve(%5B1%2Bk*exp(1.401*l)-p%2C%201%2B%20k%2B%20(tanh(l*1.401))**6-q%5D%2C%5Bk%2Cl%5D)%0A%23--%0A) . Anyone know how to solve thsi?

Comment: Please comment/answer what I'm missing here/doing wrong before downvoting the question.

Answer (score 0):

mpmath is made for doing numerical calculations and `l` is a symbol, thus the error (you used an mpmath `tanh` in your second attempt, but SymPy's tanh in the first example). You already have the solution for k from your first attempt. Solving for `l` requires solving a 12th order polynomial in exp(1.401*l) which you won't be able to do symbolically in general.

Comment: But I want the solution of k,l in terms of p,q. That's not the solution I'm getting here. How do I do that?

Comment: The first solution isn't a solution at all, Its just the value of k you get from the first equation in terms of l, ignoring the 2nd equation.

Comment: I updated my response. You are right, the value of l is not actually given.